# How do I accept the EULA while installing CUDA with run file?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, cuda

I have a very simple question: Is there anyone knowing how to accept the 'END user agreement' of the CUDA installation with run file?
tried different keys, googled but find nothing related...

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  End User License Agreement                                                  │
│  --------------------------                                                  │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│  Preface                                                                     │
│  -------                                                                     │
│                                                                              │
│  The Software License Agreement in Chapter 1 and the Supplement              │
│  in Chapter 2 contain license terms and conditions that govern               │
│  the use of NVIDIA software. By accepting this agreement, you                │
│  agree to comply with all the terms and conditions applicable                │
│  to the product(s) included herein.                                          │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│  NVIDIA Driver                                                               │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│  Description                                                                 │
│                                                                              │
│  This package contains the operating system driver and                       │
│──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────│
│ Do you accept the above EULA? (accept/decline/quit):                         │
```

Answer (score 7):

Type in `accept`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

Put `--accept-license` in the end of the command

Comment: Can you share your complete command invocation? I tried this and it said `--accept-license` was unknown.

Answer (score 3):

My fault, it seems the specific terminal that I was running the installation has some problem that I cannot get to the cursor for input accept. change to another terminal works